Spring Boot Header Validation: Multiple headers missing
I am using spring boot 2.7.18, and openapi to define rest apis. I have an rest api, which will receive multiple mandatory @NotNull Header input parameters.
I am using an ExceptionHandler in the Controller to handle the MissingRequestHeaderException. I have noticed that if there are multiple headers missing, then the ExceptionHandler will only pick on one missing header.
Is there a way for the ExceptionHandler to consume all the missing headers instead of just one?

Can you share your code here? Mean while , you can create a custom exception class that encapsulates information about all the missing headers. Handle this custom exception in your ExceptionHandler.
